# ReactJS: POST 400 (Bad Request) using Axios

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am using axios to hit an API to upload a .apk file onto a 3rd party app which is running locally on my computer. Using the API on Postman is giving the desired result but while integrating it with my React app I am getting `POST http://localhost:8000/api/v1/upload 400 (Bad Request)` error.

I have the following with structure:

*src/httpRequest.js*

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    Authorization: <API_KEY>
  }
});
```

*src/services/Upload.js*

```
import http from "../httpRequest";

const upload = (file, onUploadProgress) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);
  return http.post("/upload", formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      Authorization:
      <API_KEY>
    },
    onUploadProgress,
  });
};

export default {
  upload,
};
```

*src/components/ApkUpload.js*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const ApkUpload = () => {
  const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState(undefined);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const [currentFile, setCurrentFile] = useState(undefined);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [fileDetails, setFileDetails] = useState([]);

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', selectedFiles);
    try {
      const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/upload', data, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          Authorization: <API_KEY>,
        },
        onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
          setProgress(parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total), 10));
        },
      });
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response.status === 500) {
        setMessage('There was a problem with the server');
      } else {
        setMessage(err.response.data.message);
      }
    }
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedFiles(e.target.files);
    setCurrentFile(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/scans", {
    headers: {
      Authorization:
        <API_KEY>,
    },
  }).then(res => {
    setFileDetails(res.data.content);
  });

  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      // simple button calling above methods
    </div>
  );
};
export default ApkUpload;
```

I am using MobSF as my third party app and for upload they require multipart/form-data.

While using postman I was able to get the desired result but I'm not able to do so with my frontend. Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('file', selectedFiles[0]);
```

Inside your `handleUpload` function `selectedFiles` state is of type `FileList` but it should be `File`.

If you are handling single file then you can use:

```
data.append('file', selectedFiles[0]);
```

For multiple files you can do:

```
for(let i=0;i<selectedFiles.length;++i){
 data.append('file',selectedFiles[i])
}
```